# Spam is arriving on PLDI! What do we do about it?

Tags: discussion, spam, abuse

PLDI got its first(?) spam post today. (It got nuked within ten/five/three minutes.)

As the site grows more popular, it is almost inevitable that spam posts will start arriving. Will these spam posts be a relatively large problem and will the community need to do something about it, or will it just be a fairly trivial thing (people VTC/mods nuke)?

Comment: Could someone create and add a [spam] tag to this question (if it's a feasible question, of course)?

Comment: How does this site differ from other SE sites that you'd ask this question?

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, vote in the election if you haven't already.

Comment: @Adám I simply wanted to check if there was anything special for beta sites. Apologies if this is a bad question.

Comment: This wasn't the first spam, there have been a few others the last few days but they where dealt with swiftly

Comment: Small sites get a relatively small amount of spam in my experience. You're referring to [this post](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/2036/how-is-the-code-for-this-website-defined)?

Comment: This is already answered [in the help centre](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/help/flagging) ─ you flag it.

Comment: The answer is no different from anywhere else on the network. You flag spam/abuse as spam or rude-abusive.

Answer (score 14):

You flag them as spam and they are automatically deleted when enough flags are raised. Closing them doesn't help, and downvoting them further is marginally unhelpful (can hide it from the front page so that people don't see it to flag). This is the same procedure as on other sites on the network, but with fewer users they probably do take a little longer here.

Answer (score 10):

> What do we do about it?

Flag it. The most important thing you can do against spam, is to flag it as spam. Ordinarily, 6 spam flags will automatically delete the post<sup>1</sup>. Don't edit it out of the posts, a flag will suffice. To understand how spam flags work, please have a look at the FAQ: [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58032/269301)

> As the site grows more popular, it is almost inevitable that spam posts will start arriving.

Correct. The top 10 sites on the Stack Exchange network receive a significant portion of spam.

> Will these spam posts be a relatively large problem

Unless this site becomes one of the bigger sites, no, under normal circumstances it shouldn't be much of a problem.

> and will the community need to do something about it

Flag it.

> or will it just be a fairly trivial thing (people VTC/mods nuke)?

Under normal circumstances, spam is a fairly trivial thing. We made it into a fairly trivial thing with a project ran by the community: [Charcoal](https://charcoal-se.org/). All posts are scanned and an ever changing set of rules is used to check for spam-relevant anomalies. If the confidence level is high enough, a number of flags will be cast automatically to help taking down the posts more quickly than a single flag could. Participants can help catch spam faster by reporting posts to it and evaluating reports.

However, with the entire Charcoal project [participating in the current strike](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11540?m=63736395#63736395), spam is currently not a trivial thing.

For a longer explanation of the Charcoal project, also see: [Can a machine be taught to flag spam automatically?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291301/269301)

Does that work for beta sites too? Yes. Support for scanning PLDI was added [May 16th](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11540?m=63586297#63586297).

<sup>1</sup>: Threshold [is temporarily lowered](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11540?m=63742488#63742488) from 6 to 4 flags.

Disclaimer: I'm involved with Charcoal.

Answer (score 2):

> PLDI got its first(?) spam post today. (It got nuked within ten/five/three minutes.)

I saw it too and good that it got nuked quickly...but it isn't the first. [This actually was](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/1383/how-is-it-more-correct-to-implement-the-code-launch).

> As the site grows more popular, it is almost inevitable that spam posts will start arriving.

Correct. It is also inevitable that, provided SE doesn't [trigger a strike](https://openletter.mousetail.nl), there will be more people to fight that spam

> Will these spam posts be a relatively large problem

Not if we take care of them correctly and quickly

> and will the community need to do something about it

Yes. We'll need to **flag** it for deletion. Currently at 4 (and normally at 6) flags it's auto deleted.

> or will it just be a fairly trivial thing

Hopefully, provided we manage it right

> (people VTC/mods nuke)?

No. **People flag and then mod or bunch of people nuke**. **Don't close spam**, it's a waste of everyones time. Sure, it doesn't hurt, but it doesn't help anything either. It just needs to be deleted. Sending it the revieq queue gets it more views. Also, **don't downvote spam** because it takes it of the homepage and therefore it can remain for longer. Its also a waste of your time. Definetly, **don't vote to reopen** spam, while it shouldn't have been closed, just flagged, don't reopen it! And certainly, **don't upvote spam**. Like, seriously. All you need to do is flag as spam. Thats it!